# Filter a view result by matching a view field to a URL term

Tags: views

I have a content type called "Post" which contains two fields:

1) title
2) username

I created a View which creates a block that gathers all Posts. The block will reside on a user's account page, wherein the URL will always be:
www.mysite.com/user/username

How can I filter that block to only show the results where the username field matches the second term in the URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use contextual filter in views and set raw value as second argument from the url (here second argument will be username).